# Parsing XML through to CSV in C# using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv, parsing

I am trying to parse attributes of an xml file into a csv file, the code checks out and runs with no errors and an output CSV file is generated but contains no data

I think the problem may lie within the appending of the elements as when i tried to append another declared string to the string builder, it did not print anything out still. I have also tried changing the descendants just in case there was an error here but nothing seemed to work

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string delimiter = ",";
            XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\livingss\Desktop\XML - CSV\xml\Xml\----------.xml").Descendants("Param").ToList().ForEach(
                element => sb.Append(element.Attribute("Name").Value
                + delimiter
                + element.Attribute("PNum").Value
                + "\r\n"));

            Console.WriteLine(sb);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\livingss\Desktop\XML - CSV\Result.csv");
            sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Equipment EType="0000" Name="PlaceHolder" Version="$Revision: 2$" xmlns="urn:equipment-type">
    <EqAttributes />
    <EqVariant />
    <EqModules />
    <EqLogging />
    <EqParameters>
        <Param Name="Not Used" PNum="1">
            <Desc>Spare</Desc>
        </Param>
        <Param Name="Equipment Status" PNum="2" Min="0" Max="8" Un="1">
            <vMap>
                <Opt Name="Stopped">0</Opt>
                <Opt Name="Starting">1</Opt>
                <Opt Name="Running">2</Opt>
                <Opt Name="Stopping">3</Opt>
                <Opt Name="Standby">4</Opt>
                <Opt Name="Idle">5</Opt>
                <Opt Name="Sleep">6</Opt>
                <Opt Name="Hibernate">7</Opt>
                <Opt Name="Faulted">8</Opt>
            </vMap>
        </Param>
        <Param Name="Not Used" PNum="3" Min="0" Max="5" Un="3">
            <Desc>Spare</Desc>
        </Param>
    </EqParameters>
    <EqConfiguration>
    </EqConfiguration>
</Equipment>
```

The expected output should be the attributes for Param which are 'Name and 'PNum' the output for the first row should be 'Not Used,1'

Comment: Are you sure you get any results back from the call to `Descendants(""Param")`? Because to me it looks like you enumerate over an empty list. I tried executing your code on a dummy XML I created based on your description and then it works fine.

Comment: I have modified to include the XML file I using, hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the namespace and use it in the `Descendants` invocation:

```
XNamespace urn="urn:equipment-type";     

XDocument.Load(filePath).Descendants(urn + "Param").ToList().ForEach(...
```

Without the namespace I also don't get any results to enumerate over.

Comment: Won't that just create the string `"urn:equipment-typeParam"` as arg? That doesn't seem right. Did you mean to put a comma instead of a plus sign there?

Comment: No, that's how you create an [XName in a namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnamespace?view=netframework-4.8). The `urn` is not a string so it's not the same as string contatenation.

Comment: Huh. I see your point, yes. I didn't notice urn wasn't a string. Pretty unintuitive, how that seemingly uses string concatenations and still ends up as `XName`...

Answer (score 0):

For me the problems lies in the way you write the file.
Try and replace that:

```
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\livingss\Desktop\XML - CSV\Result.csv");
 sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
 sw.Close();
```

with that:

```
 var path = @"C:\Users\livingss\Desktop\XML - CSV\Result.csv";
 File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Still created a CSV file with no data inside

Answer (score 0):

There you go !

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string delimiter = ",";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"file.xml");
var paramElements = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Param");
for (int i = 0; i < paramElements.Count; i++)
{
    var currentElt = paramElements.Item(i);
    sb.Append(currentElt.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Name").Value);
    sb.Append(delimiter);
    sb.Append(currentElt.Attributes.GetNamedItem("PNum").Value);
    sb.AppendLine();
}

var path = @"Result.csv";
File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
```